# Listen to scroll events of RadListView

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to bind some logic to RadListView's scrollOffset (change some opacity depending on how far user has scrolled), so I want to listen to scrolledEvent, as documentation says - https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/professional-ui-components/ng-ListView/scrolling

I wanted to bind to it like to any other event in Angular, so by `(scrolledEvent)="onEvent($event)"`, but it doesn't work. Here's playground example, with working pullToRefresh event to compare to: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HzbH8p

It's possible that I'm missing something, e.g. pullToRefresh needs `pullToRefresh="true"`, but I don't see anything like that in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrolledEvent` or `scrollStartedEvent` are static constants in RadListView class holding the event names `scrolled` / `scrollStarted`.

```
<RadListView [items]="countries"
        pullToRefresh="true"
        (pullToRefreshInitiated)="onEvent($event)"
        (scrolled)="onEvent($event)"
        (scrollStarted)="onEvent($event)">
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HzbH8p&v=2)

Comment: It's really annoying that the docs aren't clear about the actual usage. I had to come here to figure out that the actual property didn't include the word "Event". https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/listview/scrolling#scroll-events